# How can I detect for a deleted row (in an Excel table) when there is only one row in the table?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to monitor table adds/updates/deletes and have been doing so via the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` and `Worksheet_Change` events.

My current problem is that neither of these events seem to fire if a deletion occurs with only 1 row in the table. Surely there is some way to detect that this change has taken place but I can't figure it out. The way I am going about the delete is to select a cell within row 1 of the table, right-click, and select Delete Row. The events fire as expected when more than a single row exists in the table, but nothing triggers if there is only a single row (until I change cells AFTER the deletion).

Any suggestions?

Comment: you seem to have come across an interesting behavior bug in Excel. I don't think it's firing because when you delete the single row in the table the row itself* does not get deleted from the table, but the data is removed. Can you change your approach (of force users to) explicitly delete the data in the row - which will fire the event.?

Comment: I think I'm going to have to take that approach. It's a shame though. I could make it work if at least the Change event fired (or any event for that matter). In the meantime, I've done exactly what you recommended as well.